# How to Convert a String value to Binary String in java

Tags: java

I need to convert a String value into Binary format.
For Example:
String str = "Java";
now i want to get it in binary format.how could i do this?
any one could please help me!

Thanks in advane

Comment: What is binary for you? What do you want to do with the value after?

Comment: In what form do you want that binary representation? A ByteBuffe? A String of 1's and 0's?

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java%20string%20to%20binrary&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp#safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=DNg&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=np&q=java+string+to+binary&spell=1&sa=X&ei=dxq4UaD8HYaAiQf3-oHAAg&ved=0CCwQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47810305,d.aGc&fp=57fbabeaac7c9348&biw=2560&bih=1470)

Comment: i wnat to get binary represenattion for the string "Java" in 1 byte.

Comment: @user2451783 give an example, this is vague.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
byte[] infoBin = null;
    infoBin = "Java".getBytes("UTF-8");
    for (byte b : infoBin) {
        System.out.println("c:" + (char) b + "-> "
                + Integer.toBinaryString(b));
    }
```

See this link : [String to binary output in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173951/string-to-binary-output-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.But it is giving 40 bits binary value for the String "Java";But i want to get 8 bit binary value for this String "Java".How could i do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(charSetName);
```

this encodes str into a sequence of bytes using the named charset, storing the result into a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

string have [getBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) method.

```
  str.getBytes();
```

Answer (score 1):

following will give you byte code;

```
 String str = "Java";
 byte[] bytecode=str.getBytes();
```